# Passing a date parameter to dynamic query for bcp

Tags: dynamic, bcp

I have the following stored procedure to copy data to a text file:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO


ALTER Procedure BCP_Inv_Text_File
(  
@FileName varchar(100),  
@DocDate varchar(10)
)  
as  
        Declare @str varchar(1000)  
        Declare @SQL varchar(1000)
        set @SQL = 'Select T0.DocNum, T0.DocDate FROM Demo88..OINV T0 WHERE DocDate = @DocDate'
        set @str='Exec Master..xp_Cmdshell ''bcp "'+@SQL+'" queryout "'+@FileName+'" -T -c'''   
        Exec(@str)  

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO
```

I then want to be able to execute the procedure similar to this:

`EXEC BCP_Inv_Text_File 'C:\Export\Inv.txt', '8/9/2013'`

I get the following error:

`Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@DocDate".`

Answer (score 0):

I found that in order to get the correct syntax on the BCP statement for the date parameter, I had to add extra single quotes, as follows:

```
    set @SQL = 'Select T0.DocNum, T0.DocDate FROM Demo88.dbo.OINV T0 WHERE T0.DocDate = ''''' + @DocDate + ''''''
    set @str='Exec Master..xp_Cmdshell ''bcp "'+@SQL+'" queryout "'+@FileName+'" -T -c'''
```